# Android - InternalSyntheticLambda onChanged$bridge crash on screen which is not related to current code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

Off late I am getting these strange crashes on some of the users devices. As per the stacktrace, the code which crashed wasn't even supposed to be executed.

```
at <package>.ProfileFragmentKt$navigationItemSelected$drawerListenerForLogout$1$onDrawerClosed$1.onClick$lambda-1(ProfileFragmentKt.java:430)
       at <package>.OveralLeaderBoard$$InternalSyntheticLambda$1$02abf2b02b6613054134ac54a51b1d4fe0a610803b5aa4ed543d8bcfe4103eb0$0.onChanged$bridge(OveralLeaderBoard.java:2)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
       at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
```

`OveralLeaderBoard` screen has *nothing* to do with `ProfileFragmentKt`.
I have never seen this `InternalSyntheticLambda`, `.onChanged$bridge` before. You won't even find it in the class kotlin bytecode.

Can anybody tell me what this is? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem in the Crashlytics console of an app in production.

I managed to reproduce the crash on my phone: there were no mention of the totally unrelated fragment in my crash logs.

If fixed the crash, and there were really no reason why this unrelated fragment should be mentionned here.

So I can't explain why, but my advice would be to ignore the unrelated fragment to anyone facing this issue.